# MySQL - Connection failed: No route to host

Tags: php, mysql, database, server

Confused why getting this issue while trying to connect to my DB.

> Connection failed: No route to host

```
<?php
$servername = "HOST";
$username = "USERNAME";
$password = "PASSWORD";
$database = "DBNAME";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";

// echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
?>
```

Can anyone provide a solution to connect?

Comment: Did you replace the placeholder values in your config variables? $servername = "HOST" $username = "USERNAME" etc. isnt getting you anywhere...

Comment: On based on code mention in question, If you write the correct credentials It will work. No issue in code

Answer (score 2):

Your `$servername` should be `localhost` not `HOST`

Change `$servername = "HOST";` to `$servername = "localhost";`

If `localhost` doesn't work, contact your web host to ask what their particular host variable is the correct IP address to use. `localhost`or `127.0.0.1` are common variables.

Also, as Adrenaxus pointed out, be sure to provide the actual username, password and database name in your variables.

Comment: It may not be localhost, but the principle is the same as the other variables - make sure you have the correct settings.

Comment: Here I gave the sample credentials and in my code it's fine. Can I know the exact reason for it? Can it be fixed from our end by code?

Comment: It does appear that your `$servername` variable is incorrect. You may want to contact your host provider to find out the proper credentials for `$servename`

Answer (score 1):

1) Check the mysql service that it is running.

2) Check the firewall that the mysql port is open.

3) If the database is located on a remote hosting check that the connection to your database can be opened.

4) If there is a router between the database, check the port forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

Declare `$PORT = '<yoursqlport>'`
Then, replace `$conn`

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database, $PORT);
```